# Hair Particle Objects change size and angle when parent object's bones are rotated

Tags: particles, armature, hair

To explain about my problem, I created a simple cube that is bent by an armature. I applied a particle system to the cube that consists of simple cones so we can see the size and angle of the particles.

When I only slightly rotate one of the bones, the particles increase their size. If I apply a subdivision modifier - as some people advise when having problems with particles - the re-sizing of the particle is no longer there, but now the angle of the particles change.

Question: How can I make the particles stay the same size and always stay normal during rotating of the structure's bones?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching the web I found the root cause of the problem: I have to apply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> *Scale*, *Rotation*, *Size*. This fixes the problem.

Frankly, I don't really understand what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> does, but it works.

Comment: It applies the scale to one. instead of 1.2 or 1.5 or anything, which is a result of you upsizing or downsizing the object somewhere midst modelling process.